# Почему Product category base переводится шотркодом product_categories и как это запретить?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня на главной странице магазина выводятся три категории товаров
с помощью шорткода woocommerce [product_categories]

Product base link не задан, то есть применяется стандартный product-category
В украинской версии сайта файл локализации есть, но он не переведен.
Показывается корректная ссылка типа https://www.pxxxxxi.com.ua/uk/product-category/hearty-pies/
То есть рабочая.
В русской версии сайта должна быть ссылка
https://www.pxxxxxi.com.ua/product-category/hearty-pies/
но показывается некоректая ссылка
[https://www.pxxxxxi.com.ua/товарная-категория/hearty-pies/](https://www.pxxxxxi.com.ua/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F/hearty-pies/)
То есть подумал я, виджет берет перевод из файла локализации.
Но когда я поменял текст перевода в файле с товарная-категория на product-category, ничего не поменялось. Я также оставлял поле перевода product-category пустым, тоже безрезультатно.
Подскажите где и что искать чтобы ссылки стали требуемого вида.

Comment: Ищи соответствующие в используемом плагине мультиязычности. И загляни в настройки ЧПУ.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.